# Div disappears on hover transition

Tags: html, css, transition

I have some problems with my CSS;

The right div disappears with it's content when it's hover transition starts and reappears when the transition (which you can't see) is done. I'd like to recreate the same as the left div transition, but then from the right.

Also, when the left div is resized, the right div also disappears.

Any ideas?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Right</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Won't you have to move the left block out of the way to allow the right block to expand into its space? I don't see CSS for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gye4yw45/1/)

Another way of doing it is by adding an extra div

```
<body>
  <div class="container">  
      <div class="left">
        <p>Left</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>Right</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and use the following CSS

```
.container:hover div.right,
.container:hover div.left   {
  width: 30vw;
}

div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw !important;
}

div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw!important;
}

div.left:hover + div.right {
  width: 30vw;
}
```

Complete CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.container:hover div.right,
.container:hover div.left   {
  width: 30vw;
}

div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw !important;
}

div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw!important;
}

div.left:hover + div.right {
  width: 30vw;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, on hover it gets larger an won't fit anymore so it gets displayed underneath the left element. Think of it like a too long word which gets on a new line instead of wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Your right div is falling down because there isn't enough room.

Look what happens when the blocks are `50vh` in the snippet below.

Consider using `absolute` or `fixed` positioning, but I don't know if this is the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/7w2265fL/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Right</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not the effect I needed, but the explanation helped me to understand what I did wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright he is what i made, not sure if it's what you're looking for :

https://jsfiddle.net/9c1pju8p/1/embedded/result/

```
<body>
<div class="left">
<p>Left</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p>Right</p>
</div>
</body>

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
   display : block;
    z-index: 2;
  width: 50vw;
    float: right;
    left: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70nr4qou/)

CSS that i've used for `.left` and `.right` is as follows

```
div.right {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #8B9ECF;
    transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #A0DB75;
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

also, the css for both the `:hover` is as follows

```
div.right:hover {
    width: 70vw;
    z-index:999;
}
div.left:hover {
    width: 70vw;
    z-index:999;
}
```

What i've done is that, i've removed the floats from your css and instead absolutely positioned the divs. Try it..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to play with the position (and left, right), like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Right</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fully possible if you're up for a JS/jQuery solution. You can make the left hover work properly with pure CSS, but since there is no way to select previous elements in CSS, JS is required to make the right side work.

For the left side, you just need the sibling selector:

```
div.left:hover ~ div.right
{
    width: 30vw;
}
```

For the right side, you'll need the following JS:

```js
$(function(){
    $("div.right").hover(function(){
        $("div.left").addClass("rhovered");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $("div.left").removeClass("rhovered");
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div.right {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background-color: #8B9ECF;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.left {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0DB75;
  transition: width 1s;
}
div.right:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
div.left:hover {
  width: 70vw;
}
div.left:hover ~ div.right
{
  width: 30vw;
}
div.left.rhovered
{
  width: 30vw;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120vh;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Right</p>
  </div>
</body>
```